# What is the difference between linux teminal types VT100 (Wyse 85) and vt100 (BS erase)

Tags: linux, terminal

When I tried to login through a linux machine through ssh, I was asked for selection of two Terminal types: VT100 (Wyse 85) and vt100 (BS erase).

I searched in google, but I couldn't get the answer.

Can any one please explain, what is difference between them and which one to select ?

Comment: That sounds like a quite old SSH client (or perhaps an old server configuration...) What are you using to connect?

Comment: I am connecting from Xwin to RHEL5 server through SSH. But, I want to know the difference between two.. so that I can select the right one.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, "VT100" is the same as "vt100".

"wy85" refers to the Wyse-85.

ncurses has terminal descriptions for `wy85` and `vt100` (or `vt102`).

You're talking about a *terminal emulator*, which of course may differ from the actual terminal.  But supposing that the terminal emulator provided by Xwin were complete, the place to look for an answer is in the report by the [**`infocmp`** program](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html).  Here is the output of a report:

```
$ infocmp -p vt100 wy85
comparing vt100 to wy85.                                                       
    comparing booleans.
        hs: F:T.
        mir: F:T.
    comparing numbers.
        vt: 3, NULL.
        wsl: NULL, 80.
    comparing strings.
        cbt: NULL, '\E[Z'.
        civis: NULL, '\E[?25l'.
        cnorm: NULL, '\E[?25h'.
        dch: NULL, '\E[%p1%dP$<3*>'.
        dch1: NULL, '\E[P$<3>'.
        dim: NULL, '\E[2m'.
        dl: NULL, '\E[%p1%dM$<3*>'.
        dl1: NULL, '\E[M$<3>'.
        dsl: NULL, '\E[40l'.
        ech: NULL, '\E[%p1%dX'.
        enacs: '\E(B\E)0', '\E)0'.
        flash: NULL, '\E[30h\E\,$<300/>\E[30l'.
        fsl: NULL, '\E[1;24r\E8'.
        ich: NULL, '\E[%p1%d@$<4*>'.
        il: NULL, '\E[%p1%dL$<5*>'.
        il1: NULL, '\E[L$<5>'.
        invis: NULL, '\E[8m'.
        ip: NULL, '$<3>'.
        is1: NULL, '\E[62;1"p\E[?5W'.
        is2: NULL, '\E[2;4;20;30l\E[?1;4;10;16l\E[12h\E[?7;8;25h$<16>'.
        is3: NULL, '\E>\E(B\E)0\017\E[m'.
        ka1: '\EOq', '\EOw'.
        ka3: '\EOs', '\EOy'.
        kb2: '\EOr', '\EOu'.
        kc1: '\EOp', '\EOq'.
        kc3: '\EOn', '\EOs'.
        kcub1: '\EOD', '\E[D'.
        kcud1: '\EOB', '\E[B'.
        kcuf1: '\EOC', '\E[C'.
        kcuu1: '\EOA', '\E[A'.
        kdch1: NULL, '\E[3~'.
        kf0: '\EOy', NULL.
        kf10: '\EOx', '\E[21~'.
        kf11: NULL, '\E[23~'.
        kf12: NULL, '\E[24~'.
        kf13: NULL, '\E[25~'.
        kf14: NULL, '\E[26~'.
        kf15: NULL, '\E[28~'.
        kf16: NULL, '\E[29~'.
        kf17: NULL, '\E[31~'.
        kf18: NULL, '\E[32~'.
        kf19: NULL, '\E[33~'.
        kf20: NULL, '\E[34~'.
        kf5: '\EOt', NULL.
        kf6: '\EOu', '\E[17~'.
        kf7: '\EOv', '\E[18~'.
        kf8: '\EOl', '\E[19~'.
        kf9: '\EOw', '\E[20~'.
        kfnd: NULL, '\E[1~'.
        khlp: NULL, '\E[28~'.
        khome: NULL, '\E[26~'.
        kich1: NULL, '\E[2~'.
        knp: NULL, '\E[6~'.
        kpp: NULL, '\E[5~'.
        kslt: NULL, '\E[4~'.
        lf1: 'pf1', 'PF1'.
        lf2: 'pf2', 'PF2'.
        lf3: 'pf3', 'PF3'.
        lf4: 'pf4', 'PF4'.
        rmir: NULL, '\E[4l'.
        rmkx: '\E[?1l\E>', '\E>'.
        rs1: NULL, '\E[13l\E[3l\E!p'.
        sgr: '\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;$<2>', '\E[0%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%p1%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p7%t;8%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;'.
        smir: NULL, '\E[4h'.
        smkx: '\E[?1h\E=', '\E[?1l\E='.
        tsl: NULL, '\E[40h\E7\E[25;%i%p1%dH'.
```

Those **`NULL`** items indicate that the feature is missing.  According to this, `wy85` has definitions for function-keys (which your PC keyboard probably has) and that the terminal supports a separate status line (far less likely).

If your chosen terminal description lacks a feature (such as function keys), most programs will not know how to handle those features.

A few differences are just due to the way the `vt100` terminal description evolved (essentially from a BSD termcap entry), so that **`flash`** is missing although the `vt100` certainly supported that.   The BSD termcap library did **not**.

The notes for the [**`wy85`** terminal description](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-wy85) indicate that the (original) terminal was emulating a VT220 (e.g., the **`ech`** line), but that is inconsistent with the `cnorm` and `civis` (show/hide the cursor), which (see [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) mentioning `DECTCEM`) came from the next model up, e.g., VT320.